# Should I use a sanitary tee or a wye into a diagonal section of pipe?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

I'm installing a temporary drain line for a kitchen sink while a remodel is taking place.  The most convenient place for me to tie in the temporary line is into a section of 2" cast iron drain line from a bathtub.  This particular section, though, is at a 45° slope.  Should I use a sanitary tee at this section? A wye?  A combo wye and 1/8?

Here's my thought process on why a sanitary tee should be acceptable, but I'm not a plumber nor a Code expert; this is just my engineering two cents.

- It's a temporary drain line (and Code would consider it a temporary line).  We're moving a kitchen (have permits, etc.), and once the new kitchen sink is installed, this temporary line will be removed (full disclosure: the remodel might take up to a year with everything else going on with the house)
- The shower is used daily.  I understand why sanitary tees aren't used in the horizontal direction (buildup), but the 45° angle should mean buildup is reduced, and the higher flowrate of a shower drain should help avoid (or at least prolong) the problem.

I have the space to use a wye or a combo, but the other geometry of the area would definitely make it easier to use the sanitary tee.  Still, I'd like to do the job properly.

Thanks!